# Division is not working

Tags: objective-c

I've got a variable:

```
int Result = 42 % 84;
```

However its returning null on NSLog?

Comment: This is not the division operator, this is modulus.

Comment: I doubt the division is not working; it's more probable there is a bug in your code. It would be better to show more code, to allow us to answer what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Show your logging code as well please!

Comment: Darron is right; `%` is the modulus operator. It's not clear why `NSLog()` is printing out `null`; the result of `42 % 84` is 42, as that is the remainder of `42 / 84`.

Comment: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html, PLEASE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To NSLog an integer, use `%d`.

```
int result = 42 % 84;
NSLog(@"%d", result);
```

Comment: @Daniel: Also, define "not working."  An error?  Output doesn't match expectations?  Be specific, please.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Where are you putting the code? What output is logged? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 2):

```
int r=42%84;
NSLog(@"%d", r);
```

The above code logs 42 for me.

Answer (score 0):

How does it return null in NSLog? Did you write "%@"?